# Socket.io: Other client only updates when being interacted

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, socket.io, observable

I'm trying to set up a realtime application using socket.io in Angular and node.js, which is not working as intended.

Whenever a client is making a new post, the other clients won't update until you interact with the client (e.g. clicking somewhere on the page, or clicking on the browsers tab).

However, having console open in the browser, I can see the new post in the console when I log the posts/objects - without the need to interact with the clients.

**Angular**:

```js
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
posts: Post[] = [];

...

// Inside ngOnInit:
socket.on('data123', (res) => {
  console.log('Updating list..', res);

  this.postService.getPosts();

  this.postsSub = this.postService.getPostUpdateListener()
    .subscribe((posts: Post[]) => {
      this.posts = posts;
    });
});
```

**Displaying in the template:**

```html
<... *ngFor="let item of posts">
```

**Inside PostsService:**

```js
getPosts() {
  this.http.get<{ message: string, posts: Post[] }>('http://localhost:3000/api/posts')
    .subscribe((postData) => {
      this.posts = postData.posts;
      this.postsUpdate.next([...this.posts]);
  });
}
```

**Node.js** - this socket.io solution is not yet sending the actual list:

```
const io = socket(server); 

io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(`new connection id: ${socket.id}`);
  sendData(socket);  
})

function sendData(socket){
  socket.emit('data123', 'TODO: send the actual updated list');

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('sending to client');
    sendData(socket);
  }, 3000);
}
```

What worked as intended: 
Using `setInterval` instead "`socket.on(..`)" on the front-end gave the intended result, meaning the clients will update automatically without the need of interacting. I'm fully aware this solution is horrible, but I assume this pinpointing that it's something wrong with socket solution above in Angular part.

Comment: It seems like a change detection problem. Try converting your posts to an Observable and then using the async flag in *ngFor

Comment: I think you're right. I'll try converting it and see how it goes.

Comment: @Dino I changed my posts to an Observable and added async pipe in *ngFor. The result is the same. It's really odd that you have to interact (clicking on some component) in order to make it update itself.  Using the  `setInterval` works without interaction, but not  `socket.on` function.

Answer (score 0):

wait, every time when socket.on('data123', (res) => {... you are creating new subscribe? it's wrong way...you must create subscribe in your socket connect feature

Comment: Yea you're totally right there, it's a terrible solution. I'm learning about observable as well. Btw what's "socket connect feature"?

Comment: if i right undestand you, you use method io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {}... here must put your subscribe logic. so, it's work once and create subscribe for your logic here. sorry my bad english)